# Get PID of a process as it opens

Tags: linux, process, pid

How do I get the pid of a process as soon as it opens. Like lets say we run ./file.pl and then ./file2.pl As both these files will create a pid in /proc/ folder. How do I instantly know if the process has been created when the executable is run.
I have a file with all the commands ready to be run as soon as it gets the green signal that there is a new process in the /proc/ folder. How do I do that?
EDIT:
Please don't answer with a shell command. I don't need to know the pid. I need to develop a script which can know right away that we have a guest in the proc department

Comment: The `/proc/` directory (not folder) is filled by the *kernel*. Every running process has some subdirectory in it (and programs don't need to do anything particular to get that created). Your question is not clear.

Comment: Please edit your question to explain really what you want to do, and show some code that you tried. Your question is unclear.

Comment: Please also explain the context, and why you want to do all this (and in which language you are coding, also show the code you have tried). There might be a simpler way to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1):

If you start the process via a shell, then start process in background:

```
./your_prog &
```

Get the pid:

```
echo $!
```

Answer (score 0):

If the script give you the shell prompt back, you can do :

```
./your_prog
pidof -x your_prog
```

Tested OK with this perl script :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

if (fork() == 0) {
    sleep(600);
}
```

you need to

```
chmod +x your_prog
```

before...

Comment: Hello @sputnick. Thanks for the response but I am looking for a script which does that. I don't want to run the file. I mean the file has more processes in it. I just want to get the pid asap

Comment: If you don't have the prompt back immediately, then you can run `pidof -x your_prog` in another pseudo-terminal

Answer (score 0):

Every process can get its own pid with the [getpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpid.2.html) syscall. At process creation by [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) the parent process (e.g. some shell) gets the pid of the new child process. Read e.g. [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) for more. And the kernel (not the program) is creating some subdirectory `/proc/1234/` see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) as soon as it creates the process of pid 1234.

Actually, `/proc/` is not a real file system. It is just a pseudo file system giving a view on the state of the kernel and the entire Linux system.

Perl gives you its [POSIX](http://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html) module to interface the syscalls. The `getpid()` syscall is interfaced using the [$PID](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24PID) or `$$` Perl variable.

The `/proc/` pseudo filesystem is filled by the kernel. You could perhaps use [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) to follow change in `/proc/` but this is very probably a bad idea.

<sup>Your question is not clear, we cannot understand what you really want to do and what you have tried.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Try out below shell script.(You may have to include changes in below script for your expected output)

```
#!/bin/bash
nr_proc_before=`ls -l /proc | wc -l`
ls /proc > proc_list_before

./any_executable &

nr_proc_after=`ls -l /proc | wc -l`
ls /proc > proc_list_after
nr_new=`expr $nr_proc_after - $nr_proc_before`

echo "$nr_new processes are created newly"
echo "new processes pids are :"
diff proc_list_after proc_list_before > new_pids
sed "1d" new_pids

if [ nr_new > 0 ] ; then
   #trigger your file which has commands.
fi
```

Insted of any_execuatble you can replace with your things so that new processes will be created.

Note : This is not a script which monitors for new process. This sample of script may give you  idea to solve your problem.
Please do reply for this answer, i can redefine my answer.